# Hive accepted invalid query and threw RuntimeException

Tags: hive, hiveql, mapr

Today, I got a strange behavior with hive (mapr distribution Hive 0.13.0-mapr-1508-21228)

Table definition:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE gd_temp_test.rate_merchants_test(
ROW_KEY string,
TRANS_DESC1 string,
TRANS_DESC2 string,
TRANS_DESC3 string,
TRANS_ID string
) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\u0001' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS textfile
LOCATION '/home/gd/tempdata';
```

When the below query is executed, it did accept the same and threw a RuntimeException.

```
select * from gd_temp_test.rate_merchants_test t1 where t1.TRANS_DESC1 limit 1;
```

Please note that the table in the query is an external table and the `TRANS_DESC1` is of `String` type.

Exception

```
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:195)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:435)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:347)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1566)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row .................

        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FilterOperator.processOp(FilterOperator.java:134)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:796)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.processOp(TableScanOperator.java:92)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:796)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:540)
        ... 9 more
```

I was expecting it to reject right at parsing or evaluating the plan for execution. 
When I did an explain query,

```
explain select * from gd_temp_test.rate_merchants_test t1 where t1.TRANS_DESC1 limit 1;
```

It was able to explain this query.

```
Explain
STAGE DEPENDENCIES:
  Stage-1 is a root stage
  Stage-0 is a root stage

STAGE PLANS:
  Stage: Stage-1
    Map Reduce
      Map Operator Tree:
          TableScan
            alias: t1
            Statistics: Num rows: 344 Data size: 1238497 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
            Filter Operator
              predicate: trans_desc1 (type: string)
              Statistics: Num rows: 172 Data size: 619248 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
              Select Operator
                expressions: row_key (type: string), trans_desc1 (type: string), trans_desc2 (type: string), trans_desc3 (type: string), trans_id (type: string)
                outputColumnNames: _col0, _col1, _col2, _col3, _col4
                Statistics: Num rows: 172 Data size: 619248 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
                Limit
                  Number of rows: 1
                  Statistics: Num rows: 1 Data size: 3600 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
                  File Output Operator
                    compressed: false
                    Statistics: Num rows: 1 Data size: 3600 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
                    table:
                        input format: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
                        output format: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
                        serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe

  Stage: Stage-0
    Fetch Operator
      limit: 1

Time taken: 0.196 seconds, Fetched: 33 row(s)
```

Any explanation what might have caused this to wait till Runtime? Is it normal behavior.

**EDIT 1:** Added example table definition.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the  [Hive datatype implicit conversions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-AllowedImplicitConversions), it doesn't allow String to Boolean conversion.

And in you query, `where t1.TRANS_DESC1` tries to read **TRANS_DESC1** as **boolean** type, that's why it throws `java.lang.ClassCastException`

Comment: But I am not able to understand this. Hive was knowing the schema of the table at the time of evaluation and it can be easily deduced that the expression can not result into Boolean. So, Why did it wait till execution in order to report a run-time error.

Answer (score -1):

please  upload your table structure and make sure all data type must same,conversion of data type is not applicable .

Comment: Added the table definition.